# How to execute awk command by python code

Tags: python, linux

I've had a set of data which I want to deal with. I was trying to run a python code to execute "awk" command in linux. hoverver no matter how I try different arguments or functions, it all didn't work.

there are two different way in which I have tried, but they all didn't work. I don't know why

1)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess as sp
cmd = "awk, '{print $2 '\t' $4 '\t' $5 '\t' $6}', B3LYPD.txt"
args = cmd.split(',')
p = sp.Popen(args, stdin = sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE )
```

2)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess as sp
cmd = "awk, '{print $2 '\t' $4 '\t' $5 '\t' $6}'"
args = cmd.split(',')
p = sp.Popen(args, stdin = sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE )
c = p.communicate('B3LYPD.txt')
print c
```

Comment: Use `shlex.split` not `str.split`.

Comment: If you are already programming in Python, are you sure you need to call `awk`? Python probably can do everything you need from `awk` just fine.

Comment: If you need a list of strings, rather than using `c = "this, that, other" ; args = cmd.split(',')`, you can just use `args = ["this", "that", "other"]` and skip the split command.

Comment: Also, Lev's comment is right, you should be able to just read the text file line by line and use the `split()` function to pick out columns, if your code here is representative of your actual `awk` pattern.

Answer (score 7):

While I agree that this is actually best done in Python, rather than invoking awk. If you really need to do this, then the actual error is with your awk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess as sp
args = ["awk", r'{OFS="\t"; print $2,$4,$5,$6}', "B3LYPD.txt"]
p = sp.Popen(args, stdin = sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE )
print(p.stdout.readline()) # will give you the first line of the awk output
```

Edit:  Fixed missing quote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use triple quotes to define the command and then *shell=True* in subprocess.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess as sp
cmd = """awk '{print $2"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6}' B3LYPD.txt"""
p = sp.Popen(cmd, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE,shell=True)
for l in p.stdout:
        print (l.decode())
```